# Jquery conflict tr:hover and .addclass in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, html-table, tablerow

The .addClass is not working for me in Firefox, it only works if I take off the `background:#f2f2f2;` from the CSS style block or `class="hovering”` out of the `<tr>` tag.
Otherwise this works in all browsers, Chrome, IE and Opera.

```
<style>

        .addToFav div{background:url('/images/star_no.png') no-repeat scroll !important; height:25px; margin:0 auto; width:25px; z-index: 999}

        .addedToFav div{background:url('/images/star_yes.png') no-repeat scroll !important; height:25px; margin:0 auto; width:25px; cursor:default;}

        tr.hovering:hover{ background-color:#f2f2f2}

</style>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
        {

        $("a.addToFav").click(function(){


            $($(this).removeClass("addToFav").addClass("addedToFav"));

        }); 

    });
</script>


            <table><tr class="hovering"><td>
                <div style="float:right"><a class="addToFav" href="#">
                <div></div>
                </a>
                </div>
            </td></tr></table>
```

Is this possibly a bug?

Comment: You don't need to wrap that second line in `$(...)`.  Probably not your solution, but still not something you should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why yours does not work but I changed the hover to a jQuery call and removed the style for the css hover.

Very weird problem.  +1 Loved it!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("a.addToFav").click(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("addToFav");
            $(this).addClass("addedToFav");
        });

        $("tr.hovering").hover(function () { $(this).addClass("trhover"); }, function () { $(this).removeClass("trhover"); });
    });
</script>


<table><tr class="hovering"><td>
    <div style="float:right">
        <a class="addToFav" href="#"><div></div></a>
    </div>
</td></tr></table>

<style>
    .trhover{ background-color:#f2f2f2 }
    .addToFav div{background:url(http://www.localisado.com/images/star_no.png) no-repeat scroll; height:25px; margin:0 auto; width:25px; z-index: 999}
    .addedToFav div{background:url(http://www.localisado.com/images/star_yes.png) no-repeat scroll; height:25px; margin:0 auto; width:25px; cursor:default;}
</style>
```

Comment: Changing the hover to a Jquery called work! yes it is a weird problem, This is my 48th hour trying to find an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In `addedToFav` class if you are setting a `background-color` then add `!important` to it. This will ensure to give more precedence in case there are other conflicting style rules in the on the page.